# List elements are in view source but not in inspect mode nor visible on the page?

Tags: html

I am working in wordpress here is my code

```
foreach($catList as $term) {
  $lstItem. = ' <li>'
    .
  '<a  data-filter="cat-'.esc_attr($term - > slug).
  '">'.esc_attr($term - > name).
  '</a>';

  $lstItem. = '</li>';

}
$lstItem. = '<li> <
  a class = "maso-order maso-filter-auto"
data - sort = "asc" >
  <
  i class = "fa fa-arrow-down" > < /i> <
  /a> <
  /li>';
//$lstItem .='</div>';
echo $lstItem;
}
`
```

In inspect Mode
[image: Inspect Mode]
[image: View Source Mode (ctrl+u)]

on my local host it is working fine. I am unable to find the difference / bug?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer its due to the hybrid composer.

Just need to add to anchor tags `class="maso-filter-auto"`  - that solved the issue.